# Iphone Facebook IOS Uploading images taking too much time?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

i am uploading photos to my facebook wall uising Facebook IOS sdk graph API. Everything is working fine here is the usual code i am using :

```
// Here i am compressing the image
NSData *yourImageData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation([_images objectAtIndex:pageIndex],0.5);

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"Photo taken with my app", @"message", yourImageData, @"source", nil];

[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

So my question is should i compress further my image? or is there another way so that the photo upload can be done faster?

Many thanks,
veer

Answer (score 0):

Please update to the new SDK 3.0.8 and use the FBRequest class

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdk-reference/iossdk/3.0/class/FBRequest/#//api/name/requestForUploadPhoto:

You can see how it can be done in the sample application as part of the SDK ( Hackbook or Scrumptuous).

Thanks!